# Play a song when double clicked

Tags: c++, qt

I created a qt media player application and have deployed it, now I want to change the properties of songs on my pc to open with it. My question is, what code should I add such that if I double click a song, its played by the media player.

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you add some more info? Here's what I can understand >> You have created a media player using C++ and now you want to play songs through it

Comment: You may want to read these links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/reparse-points , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration , https://stackoverflow.com/q/42483387/5910058

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to play the song with your app when you double click on explorer, you will have to register your app for that mime type.

Easiest way - right click on explorer, "Open with" and choose your app (`c:\programs\myapp\myapp.exe` or as a hack, directly from the build dir).

Then - in your main.cpp, look at the command line arguments. Another question to help you: [Using QApplication with command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514299/using-qapplication-with-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default open program to your media player.

[windows-10-change-default-programs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs)

[create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c)